# Ref workbook by path and name - VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

```
Sub Quack()

Dim LookupWB As Workbook
Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")

End Sub
```

This code gives an error:

> Subscript out of range
>   I think it's because of the "Set" line. 
>   How do you correctly reference a workbook by path?

If I write: `Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")` (without full path) it work perfectly.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the workbook already open, or are you trying to open it? or set a reference in a formula or something?

Comment: It's not open, I want to open it afterwards; first I want to reference it by LookupWB, then I open LookupWB. Is the plan/order of actions not ok?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you need to use the `Open` function first:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Even better: `Set LookupWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1):

If the workbook is already open, you don't need to include the path. That's why `Set LookupWB = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")` works.

If the workbook is closed, then you have to include the Open function (see @thornomad's answer).